# Extract values between commas without the quotation marks

Tags: java, regex

Let's say I have a string such as `'John','Smith'`. I want my regex to extract the values `John` and `Smith` from that string, without the commas and quotation marks. I looked around the site and found a solution that gets rid of the commas, but not the quotation marks.

This is the regex I tried `(?:^|(?<=,))[^,]*`

With that I get `'John'` and `'Smith'`. Of course, I could simply iterate over the `Matcher` like this and remove the quotation marks manually, but I was wondering if there's a more direct solution using regex without having to resort to `replaceAll`.

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(?:^|(?<=,))[^,]*");
Matcher matcher = pat.matcher("'John', 'Smith'");
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    matches.add(matcher.group().replaceAll("'", ""));
}
```

Comment: shouldn't as simple as [`this`](https://regex101.com/r/aKNBPT/1/) should  work

Comment: Hello there! Did you know that there is usually a reason for those quotation marks? Someone's first name might contain a comma. In order to not screw up your data structures, you can distinguish between a real comma and a textual one. And because this depends on the contextual quotes, parsing will not be too easy. Regular expressions cannot handle contextual info very well. Maybe just use some "CSV" library. Your task sounds like parsing a "CSV" file. It would also take some other problems off your mind, like: what if someone's first name contained quotes? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex will work: `"[^,']+"`.

Below is the updated code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String regex = "[^,']+";
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pat.matcher("'John', 'Smith'");
    List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        matches.add(matcher.group());
    }
    System.out.println(matches);
}
```

Output:

```
[John,  , Smith]
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and it gives output string without single quotes:

```
public class SubstringExample{
public static void main(String args[]){
String nameStr="'John','Smith'";
String newNameStr = nameStr.replaceAll("\'","");
System.out.println(newNameStr);
}}
```